# Добавление результата запроса в другую таблицу

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Есть вот такой запрос Select  (15*SUM(SxSy)-SUM(Sx)*SUM(Sy))/(15*SUM([Sx^2])-SUM(Sx)*SUM(Sx)) from table_1 , результат которого нужно сохранить в Table_2, столбец x. Либо вывести результат данного запроса в Text.box3. Помогите, как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Table_2 (column_name)
SELECT 
   (15*SUM(SxSy)-SUM(Sx)*SUM(Sy))/(15*SUM([Sx^2])-SUM(Sx)*SUM(Sx))
FROM table_1;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!